# How can I define an array with dynamic keys using Typescript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2, which sits on top of Angular 2.  I need to create an array of items.  I don't know how many items are going to be in that array.

Here is my Typescript, simplified:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { VgAPI } from 'videogular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-class',
  templateUrl: 'class.html'
})
export class ClassPage {
  api: any[];

  constructor(...){}

  // Load API when videos are ready
  onPlayerReady(api: VgAPI, i: any) {
    this.api[i] = api;
  }

}
```

`onPlayerReady` is called when video players in my view intialize.  `i` is the ID of that player (0, 1, 2, ...).

I'd expect this to construct an array of:

```
this.api[0] = VgAPI (of player 1)
this.api[1] = VgAPI (of player 2)
this.api[2] = VgAPI (of player 3)
this.api[3] = VgAPI (of player 4)
this.api[4] = VgAPI (of player 5)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following:

```
Runtime Error
Cannot set property '1' of undefined
```

I believe this is because `this.api[0]` isn't explicitly defined anywhere.  But that's a problem, as I don't know how many items where will be.  How can I properly define this array to allow this behaviour?

Comment: You need to set your variable as an empty array in constructor:  this.api = [];

Comment: Arrays don't have "keys", they have "indices". All arrays are dynamic, by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `api` is `undefined`, you have to set it as an empty array:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-class',
  templateUrl: 'class.html'
})
export class ClassPage {
  // initialize as empty array
  public api: VgAPI[] = [];

  constructor(...){}

  // Load API when videos are ready
  onPlayerReady(api: VgAPI, i: number) {
    this.api[i] = api;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know why someone have down voted this answer. Can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Probably because the OP's problem amounts to a typo. He got an error saying `cannot set property '1' of undefined`. Therefore, it is obvious that `this.api` is undefined. It is not surprising that `this.api` is undefined, since it was never initialized.

Comment: Not very constructive @torazaburo.  `api` is defined in the constructor - I'm aware that `api[1]` isn't defined (I stated that in my question), and I know that's why I'm getting the error, the question is why that is the case when it's set to `any` in the constructor.  This answer answers that.  Your comment is extremely unhelp, unconstructive and wrong; there was no typo, I just wasn't aware I had to initialize as an array.

Comment: @mikemike Umm, it doesn't seem that complicated to realize that if you don't initialize something, then it's not initialized. "Define" is not "initialize". Specifying a type does not initialize.

Comment: Error says `undefined`.  I am defining it.  After asking it seems I need to initialize too.  I'm not sure what your problem with all of this is...

Answer (score 1):

[Arrays in JavaScript are naturally dynamic in length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description) so you don't need to provide a size during initialization.

> Neither the length of a JavaScript array nor the types of its elements are fixed.

You haven't initialized the array, so you just need to do that, with no size.

i.e.

`api: any[];` should be `api: any[] = [];`

Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLp56nho/1/) with a little clean up.

```
interface VgAPI {
  name: string;
}

class ClassPage {
  private api: VgAPI[] = [];

  public onPlayerReady = (api: VgAPI, index: number) => {
    this.api[index] = api;
  };
}

let classPage = new ClassPage();
classPage.onPlayerReady({ name: "foo" }, 1);
```